# creating a dictionary of words in string whose values are words following that word

Tags: python, dictionary, word-count

I would like to create a dictionary from a text file using each unique word as a key and a a dictionary of the words that follow the key with the count of that word as the value. For example something that looks like this:

```
>>>string = 'This is a string'
>>>word_counts(string)
{'this': {'is': 1}, 'is': {'a': 1}, 'a': {'string': 1}}
```

Creating a dictionary of the unique words is no issue, it's creating the dictionary for the following word values I'm stuck on. I can't use an list.index() operation in case there are word repeats. Outside of that I am kind of at a loss.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) class isn't always the best choice to count something. You can use [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

def bigrams(text):
    words = text.strip().lower().split()
    counter = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for prev, current in zip(words[:-1], words[1:]):
        counter[prev][current] += 1
    return counter
```

Note that if your text contains punctuation marks as well, the line `words = text.strip().lower().split()` should be substituted with `words = re.findall(r'\w+', text.lower())`.

And if your text is so huge that the performance matters, you may consider the `pairwise` recipe from [`itertools` docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/itertools.html) or, if you're using python2, `itertools.izip` instead of `zip`.

Comment: A good solution but note that changing from `zip` to `izip` significantly reduces the run time for large collections of words (gives a ~45% reduction for list of 1M entries)

Comment: Sure, is case of python2.

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#counter-objects) to achieve what you want:

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict

def get_tokens(string):
    return string.split()  # put whatever token-parsing algorithm you want here

def word_counts(string):
    tokens = get_tokens(string)
    following_words = defaultdict(list)
    for i, token in enumerate(tokens):
        if i:
            following_words[tokens[i - 1]].append(token)
    return {token: Counter(words) for token, words in following_words.iteritems()}

string = 'this is a string'
print word_counts(string)  # {'this': Counter({'is': 1}), 'a': Counter({'string': 1}), 'is': Counter({'a': 1})}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to give an alternative option (I imagine the other answers are more suitable for your needs) you could use the `pairwise` recipe from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import tee, izip

def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
  return izip(a, b)
```

Then the function can be coded as:

```
def word_counts(string):
    words = string.split()
    result = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    for word1, word2 in pairwise(words):
        result[word1][word2] += 1
    return result
```

Test:

```
string = 'This is a string is not an int is a string'
print word_counts(string)
```

Produces:

```
{'a': {'string': 2}, 'string': {'is': 1}, 'This': {'is': 1}, 'is': {'a': 2, 'not': 1}, 'an': {'int': 1}, 'int': {'is': 1}, 'not': {'an': 1}}
```